# How can I get Velocity to output a greater than / less than without escaping it dynamically?

Tags: html, tags, velocity

I am new to Velocity and just started working on them.

I have $item.name in my velocity template. But when the item's name has "<" for eg:

Laser 3258 Adaptor - Impact 1/2"d<3/4"d

It considers < as a closing tag? Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is not specifically designed to produce HTML output, so there is no builtin facility to escape charactes for HTML.
Variable strings must be escaped dynamically. Luckily though, the escaping can be done just in line by using the helper class [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html) which is specifically designed for Java. To use it, you need to put an instance of this class in your Velocity context:

```
context.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
```

Then in your template, you can escape strings with the provided `html` method, e.g.:

```
$esc.html("2 > 0 < 1")
```

Which produces the suitable HTML output:

```
2 &gt; 0 &lt; 1
```